# Remove short overlapping string from list of string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings: `mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]`, I need to remove shorter strings that are substring of another string in the list.

For example in the case above, output should be : ["Tom Hanks","Tom Can"].

What I have done in python:

```
mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
newlst = []
for x in mylist:
    noexist = True
    for j in mylist:
        if x==j:continue
        noexist = noexist and not(x in j)         
    if (noexist==True):
        newlst.append(x)
print(newlst)
```

The code works fine. How can I make it efficient?

Comment: well one way is that the moment that `noexist` is false for an iteration you can stop checking it against rest of list, so a `if not noexist: break` inside the inner loop would gives some benefit.  not sure if there is much more to improve.

Comment: Does the order in output matter?

Comment: Hi @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I thought of something similar. I think a close idea is what you have in your answer.

Comment: @Ehsan, output order does not matter

Comment: @JesujobaALABI I added both versions in my post prior to your comment :). Feel free to use which ever suits best to your application. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan, cool! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If order in output does not matter (replace `','` character with a character that doesn't occur in strings of your list):

  ```
  mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
  mylist.sort(key = len)
  newlst = []
  for i,x in enumerate(mylist):
      if x not in ','.join(mylist[i+1:]):
          newlst.append(x)
  ```

  list comprehension alternative (less readable):

  ```
  mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
  mylist.sort(key = len)
  newlst = [x for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x not in ','.join(mylist[i+1:])]
  ```

  output:

  ```
  ['Tom Can', 'Tom Hanks']
  ```
- And if you want to keep the order:

  ```
  mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
  mylist_sorted = mylist.copy()
  mylist_sorted.sort(key = len)
  newlst = [x for i,x in enumerate(mylist_sorted) if x not in ','.join(mylist_sorted[i+1:])]
  newlst = [x for x in mylist if x in newlst]
  ```

  output:

  ```
  ['Tom Hanks', 'Tom Can']
  ```

Comment: could technically fall apart if any strings contained a `,`. Also this assumes that the substring is present at the beginning of the string for it to definitely be present in a later one when sorted, like the list `["Hanks Tom", "Tom"]` fails to remove `"Tom"`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The separation character can be adjusted according to application. You can always choose a character that you are sure it will not happen in the list. As for ordering, the sorting by string length which is already included in the post takes care of that.

Comment: ah missed the `key` in the sort, yes that will do it.  A way around the separator thing could be to do `if not any(map(x.__contains__, mylist[i+1:])` or a more verbose version of that. not sure how it'd compare performance wise. you are making a lot of slices of the list which isn't excellent.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are right. I originally thought about it and it is slower. It basically creates a double loop (maybe even slower than double loop to use map). Nonetheless, if you cannot be sure of a separation character, your suggestion is the way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See this can help you. Added answer based on question sample list :

```py
mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
newlist = []
newstring = "|".join(mylist)
for a in mylist:
    if newstring.count(a) == 1:
        print("Big string: ",a)
        newlist.append(a)
    else:
        print("Small String: ",a) 

print(newlist)
```

Added if else print statement how its traverse and check condition.

Comment: this deletes elements from the list while iterating over it, and would delete all elements if it wasn't for skipping some elements due to deleting them while iterating.

Comment: why downvote ? please explain it. output gives as expected. it will helpful if give feedback.

Comment: try it with any other order of elements, like `mylist = list(range(10))` your code is basically just deleting every second element.

Comment: Or, to further illustrate the point that the logic itself is flawed, try `[a for a in mylist if a not in mylist]`. This will produce an empty list every time because the logic goes "For each element in `mylist`, check if it's in `mylist`. If it is, skip it."

Comment: added different approach to find out. Check and give feedback. @C.Nivs

Comment: added different approach to find out. Check and give feedback. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: if this correct answer help me to upvote too. thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

a pretty minor improvement without changing the overall algorithm is that once you find another element that contains the current element then you can break out of the inner loop since it is skipped after that.

```
mylist = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
newlist = []
for elem in mylist:
    for candidate in mylist:
        if elem == candidate:
            continue
        elif elem in candidate:
            break
    else:
        newlist.append(elem)

print(newlist)
```

Comment: meh, OP asked for improvement to performance which sets the bar at `O(n^2)` complexity.  I did say it wasn't much of an improvement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Upvoting answer. and helping

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are always words, you can just split on the words and filter by `set` operations, which should be quite fast.

```
from collections import Counter

items = ["Hanks", "Tom Hanks","Tom","Tom Can"]
items = set(items)  # Don't want to think about uniqueness
item_words = {}  # {item: all_words}
word_counts = Counter()  # {word: item_counts}
word_lookups = {}  # {word: {all_words: {item, ...}, ...}, ...}
for item in items:
    words = frozenset(item.split())
    item_words[item] = words
    for word in words:
        word_lookups.setdefault(word, {}).setdefault(words, set()).add(item)
        word_counts[word] += 1

def is_ok(item):
    words = item_words[item]
    min_word = min(words, key=word_counts.__getitem__)
    if word_counts[min_word] == 1:
        return True  # This item has a unique word
    for all_words, others in word_lookups[min_word].items():
        if not words.issubset(all_words):
            continue  # Not all words present
        for other in others:
            if item == other:
                continue  # Don't remove yourself
            if item in other:
                return False
    return True  # No matches

final = [item for item in items if is_ok(item)]
```

If you want to be very fast, consider a variation on the [Aho–Corasick](https://web.archive.org/web/20190729030410/http://algo.pw/algo/64/python) algorithm, where you would construct patterns for all your entries, and match them against all your inputs, and discard any patterns that have more than one match.  This could potentially be linear in time.